# Why does Chrome attach to Selenium with --user-data-dir only, but not with specific profile path?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python 3.10.7 with Selenium 4.16.0 to automate some tasks in Chrome and encountered an issue when trying to attach Selenium to an already running Chrome instance using a specific user profile. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222")
```

To start Chrome for attaching, I've tried two different command lines. The first one specifies the user data directory along with the profile path:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\rosha\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
```

This does not seem to work as expected; Selenium does not attach to this Chrome instance. However, when I start Chrome with the --user-data-dir argument only, without specifying the profile path:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir
```

Selenium successfully attaches to the Chrome instance.

Context:

Python version: 3.10.7
Selenium version: 4.16.0
Chrome version: (Please include your Chrome version here, as it might be relevant)
Operating System: Windows 11

I am curious to know why Selenium successfully attaches to the Chrome instance when started with --user-data-dir only and not when specifying the user data directory along with the profile path.

Thank you in advance.